# Authorisation errors when deploying ARM templates to Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, security, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a couple ARM templates to an existing Azure Resource Group (RG1) from PowerShell. I'm getting authorisation errors while doing so though. The strange thing is that I'm **not** having those issues while performing the same activities on another, already existing, resource group (RG2).

I think the following information is relevant:

- I'm only having the issues while deploying to RG1 via PowerShell, I'm
  able to create resources manually in RG1 via the Azure Portal.
- I'm using the same Azure account for PowerShell and for the Azure Portal.
- The Azure account has the 'Contributor' role for both RG1 and RG2.

I'm receiving the following error when trying to deploy ARM Template Spec resources to RG1:

```
      New-AzTemplateSpec `
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

I'm receiving the following error when trying to actually 'run' the ARM templates on the RG1:

```
      New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      17:01:55 - Error: Code=AuthorizationFailed; Message=The client 'yyy@yyy.onmicrosoft.com' with object id [objectid] does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope '/subscriptions/[subscriptionid]/resourcegroups/RG-ABC/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/[deploymentid]' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

The frustrating thing is that I can't find any differences in policies or access control configuration between RG1 and RG2. They seems to be exactly the same, but of course they obviously aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without seeing the rest of your code but make sure you login:

`Login-AzAccount` - make sure you are logging in with your azure account with contributor, it will show you email under the account you login

Then you want to set your azure subscription context

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Then you can run your

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm sure I'm using the same Azure account when running the templates as when I'm in the Azure Portal. Also, I'm using the same AzContext for RG1 and RG2.

The difference really seems to be between the security configurations of the two resource groups.

Comment: It's not a policy difference if you can manually create them in azure using the same account you say you are using with powershell, it's something to due with your script. But without more information it's hard to help you.

Comment: I see your point. But the scripts are running fine for one resource group from powershell, but not for the other. While operating under the same user context. 

What additional information would you need? Happy to provide it.